# Determining the name of a .NET embedded resource?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, embedded-resource, rider

Say that you have in your C# application called **App** a directory called `Res`, and inside that directory you have *icon.png*, that presumably you will mark as **EmbeddedResource** and access it at runtime in order to provide an icon to your application, with code such as:

```
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        var resourceAppIcon = assembly.
            GetManifestResourceStream( "App.Res.icon.png" );

        // Prepare icons
        if ( resourceAppIcon != null ) {
            this.appIconBmp = new Bitmap( resourceAppIcon );
            this.Icon = Icon.FromHandle( this.appIconBmp.GetHicon());
        }
```

... and so on.

This code was working previously, but suddenly it stopped working since I changed to JetBrains Rider. Though the resources were still embedded, their names had changed from `namespace.directory.resource_name` to `namespace.resource_name`. In order to access the icon, I have to write now:

```
     var resourceAppIcon = assembly.
            GetManifestResourceStream( "App.icon.png" );
```

Is this something expected? Is it just something related to Rider? Maybe something related to the new times that come with dotnetcore? I've struggled to find documentation about this, but haven't had any luck.

EDITED: I've tried with dotnetcore using the CLI and then the resources names are as expected. It seems this is an issue with Mono?

Comment: You mention both Rider & .NET Core.  Does this reproduce in Visual Studio?  Or did you also happen to upgrade to .NET Core when you switched to Rider?

Comment: How is your CSProj including the resource(s)?

Comment: FWIW, works fine with Visual Studio, but note with Visual Studio there's the notion of Default Namespace in the project which is in general the project name but can be changed. If it's changed, the resources path are changed.

Comment: @zastrowm, I don't know, I can't use Visual Studio since I don't use Windows. I'm not using dotnetcore, but .NET framework.

Comment: @zastrowm, I have the project use the default embedded resource info:
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Res\about.png" />
...
I know I can use a LogicalName node inside, which would solve the problem, but I would like to understand why before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just trying to replay your problem but in both with dotnetcore (Visual Sutdio and JetBrains Rider) I can access the same way with your "App.Res.icon.png" code to the embedded image resource but not with "App.icon.png".

Alternatly I think you can try something like:

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); // Instead of GetEntryAssembly()
var resourceAppIcon = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App.Res.icon.png");
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: Maybe it is netframework which has changed, over Mono. I tried GetExecutingAssembly to no avail.

Comment: Yep, maybe this is an issue related to mono, after all. Please check the edit in the question.

Comment: Yes, I replayed it and the problem seem to be in mono

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the resource names are far too brittle to use them directly - if someone changes the default namespace, all resource names will change and there is no tool to refactor the resource names automatically. Thus, I always resolve embedded resources by iterating over the available resource names and find the correct one by an `EndsWith`-filter.

```
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    var resourceName = assembly.GetResourceNames().Single(n => n.EndsWith("icon.png"));
    var resourceAppIcon = assembly.
        GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is changing this, but if you are using a resx file with strings, files, etc. then you should be able to have the designer generate a code file for you with simple properties that do the right thing, then you don't have to hard-code resource names in your code, you can just access the properties on the generated `Resources` class.

If that's not an option, then my suggestion is to add some unit and/or integration tests with the names you expect and make sure they pull out the correct data.

Comment: How a resx file can be related to an embedded resource? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: A resx file allows you to put strings, files, etc. into the binary just like an embedded resource, but also provides designer support so that you can access a Resources.[PropertyName] to get at the embedded resource without caring what it's internal name is. They also provide localization support.

Answer (score 0):

The path to the embedded resource can vary based on the properties used to embed the resource.  For example, if you specify the [`ManifestResourceName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/resources/manifest-file-names#manifestresourcename-metadata) or the [`LogicalName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/resources/manifest-file-names#logicalname-metadata) property, the path will differ from the default.

Additionally, if the `EmbeddededResource` uses a [`DependentUpon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/resources/manifest-file-names#dependentupon-metadata) property and it is pointing to a C# class, then the name of the resource will attempt to match the namespace of the class being referenced, instead of the folder that the resource is located in.

Of course, the rules change if [`EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/resources/manifest-file-names#embeddedresourceusedependentuponconvention-property) is also specified in the project, in which case `DependentUpon` does not have the effected noted above.

Comment: I know I can use LogicalName, but before now, at least for me, the default was root_namespace.directory.resource, and would like to know why this has changed. I did not know about EmbeddedResourceUseDependentUponConvention, but not this nor DependentUpon is used in my project.